# Django template remove trailing comma from for loop if contition is met

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm creating a list of items with their attributes in Django. I'm getting items and their attributes from legacy database using sql stored procedures so option to get somthing like elegeant as {% for attribute in item.atributes_set.all %} is not posible.

What I have is this:

```
{% for article in articles%}
  {{article.title}}:
  {% for attribute in attributes %}
    {% if article.supplierID == attribute.SupplierID and article.ItemID = attribute.ItemID %}
      {{attribute.value}},
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a was to remove trailing comma on the last item that meet if statement condition?

Comment: looks like you are trying to perform a join in your template instead of doing it in your model or view. You should filter your list of attributes outside the template, and use [`join()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#join) template tag to add `, ` between each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like such logic in template, so I can suggest to move it into view.
Update context passed into template in following way:

```
articles_data = dict()
for article in articles:
    # following line is little bit long, but you can rewrite it with regular for loop
    # Note, attribute values should be in list
    articles_data[article.title] = [attribute.value for attribute in attributes \
                            if article.supplierID == attribute.SupplierID and article.ItemID = attribute.ItemID]
```

When you'll pass `articles_data` into template you can simply do:

```
{% for title, attributes in articles_data.items %}
    {{title}}:
    {{attributes|join:', '}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Updated answer. Initially there were mistakes

Comment: I took your good advice and move logic into view and pass a dictionary to template.
I forget to mention that attributes object dosn't have just "value" field but also a link and name... So I ended up with a list or dictionaries of articles with a nested list of dictionaries of attributes and now I can use build in template tags like "last" for that puropse.
And the best thing of all is that now page is much faster that is was when I was calling the objects in the template itself...

Answer (score 4):

It works for me:

```
{% for article in articles%}
  {{article.title}}:
  {% for attribute in attributes %}
    {% if article.supplierID == attribute.SupplierID and article.ItemID = attribute.ItemID %}

      {% if not forloop.last %}
         {{ attribute.value }},
      {% else %}
         {{ attribute.value }}
      {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

```
forloop.last
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: I know about "last" tag... but since  if statement if after for loop it is useless

Comment: Found this after two hours of searching. It is better than coding it in the view.